# AICc value How to derive?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, arima, aic

initially let me introduce a concept widely used in ARIMA in the following. $AICc = AIC + \frac {2k^2+2k} {n-k-1}$ where n denotes the sample size and k denotes the number of parameters. Thus, AICc is essentially AIC with an extra penalty term for the number of parameters. Note that as n → ∞, the extra penalty term converges to 0, and thus AICc converges to AIC. I have derived AIC value but could provide me with the proof of the extra term $\frac {2k^2+2k} {n-k-1}$ particularly used in finite samples?

Comment: Small-sample corrections often involve making an asymptotic approximation less rough, e.g. including second-order members in addition to first-order ones. So what actually happens is that you are not artificially adding a term, but simply not removing it at some point in the derivation.

Comment: Generally speaking, the combination of few samples and many parameters can yield poor modeling results. My understanding is that AICc penalizes this combination, rather than only one or the other.

Comment: You say no proof exist?